# Python single statement dictionary generator

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Is there a way in Python to do

```
new_list = [x for x in items]
```

(list comprehension) for a dictionary? Something like

```
new_dict = [x=>y for x, y in items.iteritems()]
```

so that I get

```
{x: y}
```

Comment: Note: in this specific case, you could just do: `new_dict = dict(items.iteritems())`.

Comment: Yes of course, you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by using:

```
{x: y for x, y in items.iteritems()}
```

It's called a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays), and you need Python 2.7 or newer for that syntax.

In Python 2.6 and earlier, use a generator expression and the `dict()` callable, feeding it `(key, value)` tuples:

```
dict((x, y) for x, y in items.iteritems())
```

Comment: Perfect! And thanks for the right term and reference too

Comment: Good job for keeping it backwards compatible with a 2.6 example.